# How to Insert into multiple columns from node express to MySQL db

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'd like to insert these data `name, title, body, timestamp, img_url` to a new column in MySQL. How do I achieve that.

```
  static post(name) {
    return db.execute('INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES (?)', [name]);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert multiple columns and rows into SQL Server with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840196/insert-multiple-columns-and-rows-into-sql-server-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

```
const mysqlConnection = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({...});

var query = "INSERT INTO your_table (name, email, n) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['test1', 'test@gmail.com', 1],
    ['test2', 'test1@gmail.com', 2],
];
conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is very difficult to write a insert query like this. As I have more than 20 values (fields)..